# Check if device "connected" / available

Tags: c, networking, udp, ping

I have written a program in C which communicates through udp with an Arduino.
My question is, how can I "ping" an ip address and only get a 1 or 0 (available or not) in C (unix).

The `system("ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");` call doesn't work because it outputs a list...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system("ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 > /dev/null");
```

Should do the trick. `-c 1` sends only a single packet. We pipe to `/dev/null` as we don't care about the output to stdout (is that the list you refer to?). If you also want to discard stderr, add a `2>&1` to the end. You might also want to limit the response time using `-W`.

The call will return an integer representing the success or failure. 0 indicates success, while a non-zero integer represents failure. Here's some sample code: http://ideone.com/cf0eR

Be aware that a failed ping does not guarantee that the device is offline. Although in your controlled environment, it's probably a reasonable thing to expect it to work.

Comment: I tried it but it actually doesn't output anything, if the device is connected or not...

Comment: @JNK The `system()` function returns an integer, as I explained. I purposefully discarded all other output by piping to `/dev/null`.

Comment: To discard stdout and stderr, use the POSIX-compliant `>/dev/null 2>&1` instead of the bashism `&>/dev/null`. On many systems `system()` does not use bash and `&>/dev/null` will place `ping` in the background followed by an empty command redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @jilles Did not know that! Edited it in.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can not determine whther a network host is up - a member of an IP network is allowed not to send any packets. The best way is to just start communication and use a protocol that requires the contacted machine to answer in any way.

However, if you are sure the machine answers to ping, but not your UDP packets, use `ping -c 1 192.0.32.10`. This solution is very brittle though:

- The machine may not answer to ping
- The network(i.e. a firewall in between you and the host) may not relay your ping message, but would relay UDP packets fine
- The network can actually change at any time. When you receive an ping reply, all you know is that the remote host **was** up when you sent the message